# MySQL procedure - how to improve performance of query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL procedure which is collecting data from 3 tables:

- dossier
- courrier
- courrier_concerne_dossier

Simply I just can't use select * from... I need every dossier_str separated (one dossier_str in each column and all in one big result set).

```
    (SELECT dossier_oid from data.courrier_concerne_dossier where courrier_oid = param_oid LIMIT 1) as 'dossier1_oid',
                (SELECT concat(a.prefixe_numero, "-", cast(a.numero as char), " - ",DATE_FORMAT(a.date_ouverture, '%e/%c/%Y'), " - ", b.nom, " - ", a.intitule) 
                    FROM data.dossier as a
                    JOIN data.client as b on
                        a.client_oid=b.oid
                    WHERE a.oid = dossier1_oid) as 'dossier1_str',

    (SELECT dossier_oid from data.courrier_concerne_dossier where courrier_oid = param_oid LIMIT 1,1) as 'dossier2_oid',
            (SELECT concat(a.prefixe_numero, "-", cast(a.numero as char), " - ",DATE_FORMAT(a.date_ouverture, '%e/%c/%Y'), " - ", b.nom, " - ", a.intitule) 
                FROM data.dossier as a
                JOIN data.client as b on
                    a.client_oid=b.oid
                WHERE a.oid = dossier2_oid) as 'dossier2_str',

    (SELECT dossier_oid from data.courrier_concerne_dossier where courrier_oid = param_oid LIMIT 2,1) as 'dossier3_oid',
            (SELECT concat(a.prefixe_numero, "-", cast(a.numero as char), " - ",DATE_FORMAT(a.date_ouverture, '%e/%c/%Y'), " - ", b.nom, " - ", a.intitule) 
                FROM data.dossier as a
                JOIN data.client as b on
                    a.client_oid=b.oid
                WHERE a.oid = dossier3_oid) as 'dossier3_str',
```

Comment: Looks like a pivot table to me.
Maybe this helps:[MySql-Pivottables](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)

Comment: Please could you show some example data?  Also, I note that you use `LIMIT 1,1` to get *'the second dossier_oid'*.  Without an `ORDER BY`, however, there is no actual guarantee that this will always return the same value *(You **really** can get different results another day)*.  Does the table `data.courrier_concerne_dossier` have any other fields that would allow you to determine which record corresponds to `dodssier3_oid`?  *(The more relevant data you include in an example case the better.)*

Comment: Is this query intended to bring back one row, or many rows. The 6 sub queries are not going to be efficient, but for a single returned row they will probably be acceptable. For many returned rows they would likely be very slow. In the abscence of the full query it is impossible to know. However changing these to joins would likely be faster if there are multiple rows

Comment: Well I think pivot table example will be helpfull. I gonna study it tomorrow. Whole procedure got about 50 selects and time is like 200 ms max, but it's not acceptable for the client. Data is connected to Courrier (Emails), and I have GridView with 200 emails, every select of email procedure is returning 50 dossiers. That 200 ms of delay is my top1 problem and I am trying to figure out best solution.